# Why are BatchInserterIndex exact queries of multiple fields returning all nodes?

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

I'm loading a pile of data (14M nodes, 460M edges) into a neo4j database, and using BatchInserter to do it for performance purposes. I'm loading the data in two passes: first nodes, then edges, using a BatchInserterIndex to query for the nodeIDs when edges are added.

Each node has two properties:

- name
- type

Name is not unique, but Name+Type is. This means I cannot query the index using `get(String key, Obj value)`; so I am using `query(Object query)`, which is poorly documented. I cribbed from the Ruby docs, where it looks like the query object is expected to be a Lucene query.

However, when I do a query for `name:"thename" type:"thetype"`, I get back a list of all the nodes in the database.

If all else fails I can add a third property "nametype" just for the purpose of having unique IDs for batch insertion, but I'd rather not if I don't have to. Any idea what's going on?

Snippet:

```
// the load-nodes phase:
BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(dbDir);
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = 
    new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider( inserter );
BatchInserterIndex nodes = 
    indexProvider.nodeIndex( NODEINDEX, MapUtil.stringMap( "type", "exact" ) );

// for file in filelist
    // all nodes in a file have the same type
    properties.put( NODETYPE_KEY, types.get(file) );
    // for line in file:
        properties.put( NODENAME_KEY, line );
        long node = inserter.createNode( properties );
        nodes.add(node, properties);
    // \for
// \for

// ...

// the load-edges phase:
BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(dbDir);
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = 
    new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider( inserter );
BatchInserterIndex nodes = 
    indexProvider.nodeIndex( NODEINDEX, MapUtil.stringMap( "type", "exact" ) );
nodes.setCacheCapacity( NODENAME_KEY, cache );

// for line in file
    String fromType = fromTypes.get(file);
    String fromName = parseFromName(line);
    String query = String.format("%s:\"%s\" %s:\"%s\"",
        NODETYPE_KEY,fromType,NODENAME_KEY,fromName);
    IndexHits<Long> froms = nodes.query(query);
    // froms has #nodes results ?!
// \for
```

Answer (score 1):

Aaaaaaaaaaa the default conjunction in Lucene is "OR". :-/

I explicitly made it AND and it worked.

Additionally, I tried the third-key concatenation-of-type-and-name alternative. It looks like index.get(key, val) is about twice as fast as index.query(lucene_expression) in this case, and constructing and storing the extra property makes node-loading about 50% slower. Since my dataset has 40x as many relations as nodes, it actually makes sense to add the extra property to every node. YMMV.